# Vertical align with bootstrap not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Maybe I don't have it setup right? I've been looking at code for the past 3 hours so it's possible I'm over looking something. Either way I have this h3 in a div and I want it to be centered both horizontally and vertically, however only horizontal is working.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="align-items-center" style="background-image:url({{ uni.u_homepage_pic.url }}); background-repeat:no-repeat; width: 350px; height: 225px;">
        <h3 class="text-center" style="color:#ffffff;">{{ uni.u_name }</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Update: Using Bootstrap V4**

Comment: Try `.align-items-center { width:100%; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);}`. Add `position: absolute;` if it doesn't work.

Comment: Try to look at this demo :
[link](https://www.bootply.com/jTZdTJGVzq)

Comment: at least provide us your bootstrap version, because BS4 has huge differences with BS3

Comment: @LeandroRuel Sorry just added that, It's version 4

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```css
.align-items-center {
  display: flex; 
  align-items: center;  /*Aligns vertically center */
  justify-content: center; /*Aligns horizontally center */
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="align-items-center" style="background:red; width: 350px; height: 225px;">
    <h3 class="text-center" style="">Hello</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Aren't these the class I have?

Comment: Add that css to your .align-items-center and it will align them like you need.

Comment: It worked thanks, Does bootstrap not have this vertical align feature itself?

Comment: For bootstrap 4, there is the feature of align-items-center on the row classes containers but I find this simple and more effecient :)

Comment: This changes all the content objects to inline blocks or something, they are no longer stacked.

Answer (score 10):

This answer is for bootstrap 4:

To vertically align the column content, you can use `my-auto` class in column itself:

```
<div class="col-md-4 my-auto">
    <div style="background-image:url({{ uni.u_homepage_pic.url }}); 
        background-repeat:no-repeat; width: 350px; height: 225px;">
        <h3 class="text-center" style="color:#ffffff;">
           {{ uni.u_name }
        </h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Further, to align the items inside a column horizontally, you can use `mx-auto` and for both horizontal and vertical alignment, use `m-auto`. Horizontal align will work for single column.

---

To align all the columns, you need to supply the **`align-items-*`** classes inside the `row` element but not inside the `col` element:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row align-items-start"><!-- align contents to top -->
    <div class="col">
      Top A
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      Top B
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      Top C
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row align-items-center"><!-- align contents to center -->
    <div class="col">
      Mid A
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      Mid B
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      Mid C
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row align-items-end"><!-- align contents to end -->
    <div class="col">
      Bottom A
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      Bottom B
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      Bottom C
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

try with flex and align-self-center:

```
<div class=”row”>
   <div class=”col-6 align-self-center”>
      <div class=”card card-block”>
      Center
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class=”col-6">
      <div class=”card card-inverse card-danger”>
      Taller
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

check this css

```
<div class="col-md-4">
        <h3 class="centered">{{ uni.u_name }</h3>
</div>
```

and this is the css (put it in the head tag)

```
<style>
.centered {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row !important;
    align-content: center !important;
    justify-content: center !important;
    align-self: center !important;
    align-items: center !important;
    margin:auto;
    background-image:url({{ uni.u_homepage_pic.url }});
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width: 350px; 
    height: 225px;
    color:#ffffff;
}
<style>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this like in my example: https://jsfiddle.net/h5xofjqf/
or you just need set a **fixed height** to your container, then, the `h1` would have a

```
h1 {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Property is a margin:auto; ...Do this

Comment: margin:auto is the right answer but the missing info is that you have to place it on the containing element.